# I want to use jQuery cookie, but I cant find the cookie method

Tags: jquery, plugins, cookies

What should I do, which is the best jQuery cookie  plugin?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the jquery-cookie plugin available at Github: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

You can set the cookie value by:

```
$.cookie('cookie_name', 'cookie_value');
```

And get the value back by:

```
var cval = $.cookie('cookie_name');
```

And delete the cookie by:

```
$.cookie('cookie_name', null);
```

Comment: can this be used for dictionary's

Comment: @gov, have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/804834/serializing-a-dictionary-for-cookies

Answer (score 1):

Check out:

- [Setting cookies with jQuery](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-cookies/)
- [jQuery & Cookies (get/set/delete & a plugin)](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2010/09/jquery-cookies-getsetdelete-plugin.html)

Comment: can this be used to get cookie dictinonary , we have lot of dictinary, if this can support , i will start using it.